Button doesn't recognize functions
I have this HTML:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Tu Sitio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="paginaUsuarioServicio.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
      <a href="paginaPrincipalUsuario.html">Bienvenida</a>
      <a href="paginaUsuarioMascotas.html">Tu Mascota</a>
      <a href="paginaUsuariosServicio.html">Servicios</a>
      <a href="paginaUsuarioAgregar.html">Agregar Mascota</a>
      <a href="login.html">Cerrar Sesión</a>
    </nav>

    <div class="content-wrapper">
      <div id="map"></div>
      <div id="dataContainer">
        <p id="TiendasVinculadas">Tiendas Vinculadas</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="chat-popup" id="myForm">
      <form class="form-container" action="#">
        <h1 style="color: #5d17cf">Chat</h1>
        <textarea
          placeholder="Escriba su mensaje..."
          name="msg"
          required
        ></textarea>

        <button type="submit" class="btn">Enviar</button>
        <button type="button" name="btn cancel" onclick="closeForm()">
          Cerrar
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>

    <script type="module" src="/dist/paginaUsuarioServicio.js"></script>
    <script
      async
      defer
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={API_KEY}&libraries=places&callback=initMap"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>

And this JS:
import { getDocs, getDoc, query, collection, doc, where} from 'firebase/firestore';
import { db } from './index.js';

function openForm(){
    document.getElementById("myForm").style.display="block";
}
function closeForm(){
    document.getElementById("myForm").style.display="none";
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async () => {
    openForm();
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    const additionalData = urlParams.get('data');
    const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('nav a');
    const verButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.ver-button');


    navLinks.forEach(link => {
        const linkUrl = link.getAttribute('href');

        if (link.textContent.toLowerCase() !== 'cerrar sesión') {
            const separator = linkUrl.includes('?') ? '&' : '?';
            link.setAttribute('href', `${linkUrl}${separator}data=${additionalData}`);
        }
    });


    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            position => {
                const userLocation = {
                    lat: position.coords.latitude,
                    lng: position.coords.longitude
                };

                initMap(userLocation);
                addPetPlaces(userLocation);
            },
            error => {
                console.error('Error obteniendo la ubicación:', error.message);
                initMap({ lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 });
            }
        );
    } else {
        console.error('Geolocalización no es compatible en este navegador.');
        initMap({ lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 });
    }

    const usuariosCollection = collection(db, 'Usuarios');
    const queryUsuarios = query(usuariosCollection, where('rol', '==', 'DueñoServicio'));

    try {
        const usuariosSnapshot = await getDocs(queryUsuarios);

        for (const usuarioDoc of usuariosSnapshot.docs) {
            const usuarioData = usuarioDoc.data();
            const usuarioId = usuarioDoc.id;

            const usuarioDocRef = doc(usuariosCollection, usuarioId);
            const usuarioDocSnapshot = await getDoc(usuarioDocRef);

            if (usuarioDocSnapshot.exists()) {
                const usuarioInfo = usuarioDocSnapshot.data();

                const tiendasCollection = collection(usuariosCollection, usuarioId, 'Tiendas');
                const tiendasSnapshot = await getDocs(tiendasCollection);

                tiendasSnapshot.forEach(tiendaDoc => {
                    const tiendaData = tiendaDoc.data();
                    const nombreTienda = tiendaData.nombre;


                    const contenidoHTML = `
            <div class="tienda-box">
                <h3>${nombreTienda}</h3>
                <p>Nombre: ${usuarioInfo.Nombre} ${usuarioInfo.Apellido}</p>
                <p>Servicio Tienda: ${usuarioInfo.ServicioTienda}</p>   
                <p>Correo: ${usuarioInfo.correo}</p>      
                <button id = "open" onClick="openForm()">Mensaje</button>
                <button onclick="verUbicacion('${nombreTienda}')">Ubicación</button>
        </div>      
                    `;
                    dataContainer.innerHTML += contenidoHTML;
                });
            }
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error al obtener datos de las tiendas:', error);
    }
});

let map;

function initMap(userLocation) {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: userLocation,
        zoom: 15,
    });
}
function addPetPlaces(userLocation) {
    const request = {
        location: userLocation,
        radius: 5000, 
        type: ['pet_store']
    };

    const placesService = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

    placesService.nearbySearch(request, (results, status) => {
        if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            for (const place of results) {
                const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: place.geometry.location,
                    map: map,
                    title: place.name
                });
            }
        }
    });
}

function verUbicacion(nombreTienda) {

    console.log(`Ver ubicación de ${nombreTienda}`);
}


The problem is, that I want to do a popup, but the buttons doesn't recognize the functions to open and close the chat.
In console it shows this exception

Uncaught ReferenceError: closeForm is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (paginaUsuariosServicio.htmldata=Usuario1:35:71)

in both cases

Are there any console errors? Are you developing locally? If you are, and you're not runnig a local server, then CORS is preventing your local JS file from loading.

I am getting this console error: :Uncaught ReferenceError: closeForm is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (paginaUsuariosServicio.htmldata=Usuario1:35:71)
And I'm developing locally but I'm using a local server from a VS extension

It makes me wonder if there's another error in your JS, that it's having trouble finding. Maybe comment out the body of the function and see if it still happens. Or remove the function altogether (and the call from the onclick) and see if another error is shown.

It's because the script is a module. The functions aren't available in the global scope used by onclick. See the linked question.
